# How can I create a stored procedure with an insert?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I created the next table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Compras(
    Compra              INT               NOT NULL,
    Proveedor           INT               NOT NULL,
    FormaDePago         varchar(10),
    Saldo               DECIMAL(15, 3),
    Fecha_Compra        DATE              NOT NULL,
    Condicion_Compra    VARCHAR(10)       NOT NULL,
    Deposito            INT               NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Compra)
)ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

I have an error when I try to create the next stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE comprarx(IN pk INT, 
                         IN proveedor INT,
                         IN pago varchar(10),
                         IN saldo decimal(15,3),
                         IN fecha DATE,
                         IN condicion_compra varchar(10),
                         IN deposito INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Compras
    VALUES(pk, proveedor, pago, saldo, fecha, condicion_compra, deposito );
END
```

I don't know what my mistake is.

Comment: Your stored procedure input parameters don't have the same data types as the columns in the table.

Comment: @sgeddes no that's not it :P

Comment: I corrected it but still I have the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any error in your code except the `DELIMITER`. Try this,

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE comprar(IN pk INT, 
                         IN proveedor INT,
                         IN pago varchar(20),
                         IN saldo INT,
                         IN fecha DATE,
                         IN condicion_compra varchar(10),
                         IN deposito INT)
BEGIN

        INSERT INTO Compras
        VALUES(pk, proveedor, pago, saldo, fecha, condicion_compra, deposito );

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```